# Does the SDK provide a way to group Annotations, like on Photos (places)

Tags: iphone

I would like to implement a similar effect where the pins are grouped together then separate with an animation as you get closer to the points. This effect is seen in the Photos app when you select Places with geotagged apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it doesnt but there is a 3rd party library which provides this functionality:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtclustermaker/

Answer (score 0):

Or the same thing for free. :)
https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView

Believe it or not, i'am the developer of this thing!
I have absolutely no benefits by promoting my own open source thingy and just want to help you save time and money. If you pay with down votes alright, i take them all. It is still open source and free for all. :D

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation when promoting your own product, project, blog, etc.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is this code also for free https://github.com/romaonthego/REMarkerClusterer